# Hearing disturbing murmer when headphones are plugged in

Tags: audio, drivers, windows-8.1

This question has been here for a few times already, still no reasonable answer has been given yet.

I have bought a brand new notebook and installed audio drivers and codecs, everything works just fine but headphones. When I plug them in I can hear murmuring, popping sound - even when the music is not playing. I'd decribe the sound as the sound in headphones when you have volume on maximum and not playing music but ten times worse. I tried to reinstall the drivers, older drivers, different drivers. Nothing works. I'd aapreciate any help.
Notebook is Lenovo IdeaPad Z510. Drivers directly from Lenovo don't help either.

BTW: I had the same problem on the old notebook, which was solved by installing the older driver.

Comment: Have you tried using a different pair of headphones to determine if the problem is with the notebook or with the headphones? Are they noise cancelling headphones? Have you muted the built in microphone on the computer?

Comment: Yes I have tried different headphones - it's not it. And yes, I have tried to mute the internal microphone - and still nothing.